# Align text next to an image that has "top" set

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

My first question is: Why isn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tnk2xp4f/2/) working?

1. The text should be in the middle of the image, not in the bottom, Since I used `vertical-align: middle;`.
2. There should be some space between the image and the top, since I used `top: 10%;`.

```css
.card {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.card .inline-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.card #person-photo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .photo{
  top: 10%;
}

.card #person-photo, .card #details {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" dir="rtl">
    <div id="person-photo">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/mwy4v3h" class="photo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-container">
        <div id="details">hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my second question is how to:

1. Make a text be near an image (to the left of it), vertically aligned to the middle of the image with a way to configure its `top` in percentage of the image's `height` (if the image gets shorter, the text becomes higher).
2. Make the image `top` configurable in percentage of its container's `height` (when the container gets shorter, the image becomes higher).

(When I say configure I mean with CSS, using constant numbers which I will choose in advance)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

See the [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/tnk2xp4f/3/) so far.

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` should be on the image

Comment: Thank you! You answered the "why isn't this working - 1". It's so weird that it should be on the image, though...

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
<p>This is some text.<img src="http://tinyurl.com/mwy4v3h" align="top"/>again some text </p>
```

Comment: This only aligns the text to the middle of the image, which was already solved by j08691. What about the other questions? Like how to set the top of the text in percentage of the image's height? Thanks

Comment: remember if you place your text on the image you have less control on your text ... the best is using margin or padding for positioning your text where you want

Comment: Then it won't be relative to the height but to the width. Also just wanted to clarify that the text is next to the image and not on it.